How can I enable function level linking with a Windows 64 bit assembly file
I need to have several hundred functions written in assembler. They will be statically linked into an executable. I only want the functions that are actually referenced to be included in the executable.
I could achieve this by putting each function into a separate assembler file, assembling each file, creating a .lib from all the resulting objects, and linking against the .lib. As the C compiler supports function level linking, I feel there should be a way to do this in a single assembly file.
Each function will have a little block of static data. Again, this should only be included if the function that uses it is referenced.
It must be statically linked. Putting everything into a dll is not an option.

/Gy[-] - simply run ml64 /? and you view this option

if run
ML64.exe /?

we can get next line in output:
/Gy[-] separate functions for linker 

which is coincides with /Gy (Enable Function-Level Linking)

Thank you. That works perfectly for the code part. All of the data is pulled in though. How could I structure the data declarations so that only the data referenced by an individual function is pulled into the final executable.

I could not find a way to replicate the per object modularity that individual object gave, so I wnet back to having individual objects. However - I was able to speed up my build time considerably, which is what ultimately drove this question, by passing batches of 64 assembler files to ml64 at a time.
